# install ubuntu 20.04 - locks up during installation

Tags: system-installation, iso

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04-desktop-amd64 from an iso onto, well, anything. 18 minutes into the installation it is performing it's "copying" action and it stops.

I've tried installing from the iso on:

- a HP ProLiant MicroServer Gen8 with 10GB ecc ram.
- A VirtualBox (6.1.10) machine hosted on Windows 10 version 2004 from iso, where other VMs already run, with 4gb ram assigned.
- A virtualBox (6.1.12) machine hosted on macos catalina with 8gb ram assigned.
- A atom-based laptop with 4gb of ram, via a burned usb stick

I've tried redownloading the iso.

As soon as it says "copying" it spins for a couple of minutes then goes unresponsive.

Other debian based OS's install and run fine on the same hardware or configurations. What can I do to figure out the exact point that the copying stops and discern the reason behind it failing?

Comment: Did you validate the ISO?   If I have a bad install, I usually switch to a text terminal & explore the system to work out what is going on, where the install is at (or if squashfs errors are occurring, which signify a bad ISO or more likely a write to install media)

Comment: Yes, I let the internal check thing happen at the start after the first time failed. I then proceeded to redownload the iso anyway. the checksum matches the site. I would switch to a terminal IF the installer would let me, but when it locks up it's totally unresponsive and it's power-off time.

Comment: You didn't specifically state that you verified the ISO after download (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) as the validation of media really detects a bad write to media, it cannot be trusted if the code itself is invalid (ie. ISO verification is still required). SysRq keys usually tell me if it's completely locked (ie. keyboard straight to kernel) as your vague *totally unresponsive* doesn't tell me what isn't responding, if SysRq key combinations won't respond either keyboard is dead, or kernel is dead (switching to term requires more than kernel)